# This recurrence relation will evaluate to?

Tags: recurrence-relations

T(n) = 2T(n-1)+n,     n>=2
T(1) = 1

What will this recurrence relation equation evaluate to ?

I used substitution method and found out that this relation takes the form 2^k T(n-k) + 2^(k-1) * (n-(k-1)) + 2^(k-2) * (n-(k-2)) + ... + n

Comment: What did you find so far, how did you tackle this?

Comment: I used substitution method and found out that this relation takes the form 2^k T(n-k) + 2^(k-1) * (n-(k-1)) + 2^(k-2) * (n-(k-2)) + ... + n

Comment: Now I am unable to solve summation (2^(n-i) * i) for i = 0 to k-1

Comment: Did you get my approach? I can provide you with more details if you need to

Answer (score 1):

Dividing the both sides by $2^n$ gives us
$$\frac{T(n)}{2^n}=\frac{2T(n-1)}{2^n}+\frac{n}{2^n}\iff \frac{T(n)}{2^n}=\frac{T(n-1)}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{n}{2^n}.$$
So, setting 
$$U(n)=\frac{T(n)}{2^n}$$
gives us
$$U(n)=U(n-1)+\frac{n}{2^n}.$$
So, we have for $n\ge 2$
$$\begin{align}U(n)=U(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}.\end{align}$$

P.S. Let $S=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$. Then we have
$$S=\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^3}+\frac{4}{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n}$$
$$\frac 12S=\frac{2}{2^3}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{n-1}{2^n}+\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}$$
So, we have
$$S-\frac 12S=\frac{2}{2^2}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}}-\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}.$$
Since $$\color{red}{\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}}=\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2^n},$$
we have
$$S=2\left(\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}\right).$$

Comment: Hey thanks for helping but I am a little weak in maths. Can you please provide the complete solution ?

Comment: @Rakesh: Well, I added a bit. Do you know how to find the sum at the last?

Comment: Unfortunately No :(

Comment: @Rakesh: I added a bit again. How about that?

Comment: Can you help me solve this summation $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{2^{n+i}}i.\end{align}$$

Comment: @Rakesh: Before asking another question, please react to my another addition.

Comment: Are we finding the same thing? My solution holds at least for the four first terms of the sequence, I think it's correct but I don't see how one can switch from one result to another rapidly

Comment: @mvggz: I got the same result because $S=\frac 32-\frac{2+n}{2^n}\Rightarrow U(n)=2-\frac{2+n}{2^n}\Rightarrow T(n)=2^{n+1}-2-n$.

Comment: Fair enough :) , should have done this myself. I like both ways but I don't know if Rakesh will ever choose one

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $T(n)=S(n)+an+b$

$$S(n)+an+b=2[S(n-1)+a(n-1)+b]+n$$

$$S(n) =2S(n-1)+(a+1)n+2b-2a$$

Set $a+1=2b-2a=0$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V_n$ = $\frac{T_n}{2^n}$

Dividing your relation by $2^n$ , you get :

$ V_n = V_{n-1} + \frac{n}{2^n}$

->  $ V_n = \sum_{k=1..n} \frac{k}{2^k}  $ The sum is from k=2..n but the term k = 1 is $V_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{1}{2^1}$

You can evaluate this sum pretty easily, using geometrical series and standard methods ( like deriving $\sum_{k=0..n} x^k $ into  $\sum_{k=1..n} k*x^{k-1}$ .

Let f be: f(x) = $\sum_{k=0..n} x^k$

$f'x)$ = $\sum_{k=1..n} k*x^{k-1}$ (ok?)

So : $\sum_{k=1..n} k*x^{k}$ = x*$\sum_{k=1..n} k*x^{k-1}$ = $x*f'(x)$

From common knowledge : $f(x) = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} $

$f'(x) = \frac{1- (n+1)*(1-x)*x^{n} - x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}$

What we're looking for is the case: $x = \frac{1}{2}$

So $V_n = \frac{1}{2}*f'(1/2) = 2*(1-\frac{n+2}{2^{n+1}})$

$T_n = 2^n*V_n = 2^{n+1}  - (n+2)$