# Solving recurrence equations with repeated substitution?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Say we have a recurrence equation as

$$
T(n) =
\begin{cases}
T\left(\frac n2\right) +n & \text{if }n\ge2 \\
1 & \text{if }n=1
\end{cases}
$$

Would the first substitution be like this?

$$\left(T\left(\frac n4\right) + \frac n2\right) + n$$

A little confused with these. If you could show the first 3 or so steps, or any other help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975064/this-recurrence-relation-will-evaluate-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n = 2^k$.

$$\begin{align}T\left(n\right) & = T\left(\frac n2\right) + n \\ 
&= \left[T\left(\frac n4\right) + \frac n2\right] + n\\
& = \left[T\left(\frac n8\right) + \frac n4\right] + \frac n2 + n\\
& = \dots\\
& = T\left(\frac n{2^k}\right) + \left[n + \frac n2 + \frac n4 + \cdots + \frac{n}{2^{k-1}}\right]\\
& = 2n - 1\end{align}$$

Comment: Okay and would nlogn be big theta of this recursive equation?